# Starting new Android application

Tags: java, android

I am about to start new Android app considering that Java development is not my strongest side I'd like some advice on where to start. The question is not that much about Android API it's more about the right tools and code organisation.

- Should I use template app like [Android Bootstrap](https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap) and are there any other better than that.
- How should I organize my code so it makes sense while the app grow.
- Any other libraries that might help?

The app would be for downloading music and it'd be free one. There would be a server API that will deliver the content.

Comment: the question belongs to another site:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130427/what-is-the-best-way-to-structure-an-android-application/130855#130855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In my opinion you should start with a blank project and try to learn Java and understand how the classes in Android work. Using a template is not the best way to learn programming because you can easily get confused and not understand what the code does.
2. You implement the classic [3-Tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture) with packages for the Domain, Repository, Controller and User Interface. This way you can stay organized and easily improve on your app.
3. Read Android forums, documentation and see what libraries do you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get stronger on Java development, [go through the Java SE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Then you can take a look at the [Android Development Getting Started page](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

I'd also recommend you to invest on some good programming book

Comment: I am not newbie into Java and Android, actually I already have one live APP with 20K downloads the thing is its code is mess and I want to avoid that with the new APP

Comment: In that case some reading on OO design pattern might suit you

Comment: In my opinion 3-tier architecture is the way to go. Domain (Data Classes, ex: Student, Dog etc.), Repository (ListOfStudents Class, ListOfDogs Class etc.), Controller (Class that makes the connection between the UI and the Domain, other methods), User Interface (Your views, buttons etc.)